# How to change SQL Connection string from server to Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

Currently my project connects to a database on the schools network using this connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Provider" connectionString="server=.;uid=sa;pwd=****;database=decider;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But my database at home uses Windows authentication.
How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the key/value pairs for `uid=sa` and for `pwd=***` add `Trusted_Connection=True;`

```
<add name="Provider" connectionString="server=.;database=decider;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
```

This, of course, if you want a manual solution editing the config file.
If you want a solution via code then take a look at the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class

This class could be instantiated using a current connection string and then changing its properties to suit your different environement

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder scb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(yourConnectionFromConfig);
scb.Remove("uid");
scb.Remove("pwd");
scb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
string yourNewConnectionString = scb.ToString();
```